# HTMLUNIT Anchor click

Tags: anchor, htmlunit

My Anchor looks like :

```
<div class="button-cont main">

          <input type="hidden" name="ak.ok" value="" />
          <input type="hidden" name="ak.cancel" value="" />

      <a id="log-in" onclick="postOk();" class="log-button normal allow" title="LOG IN">
     LOG IN

          </a> 

        </div>
```

My Code looks like :

```
 HtmlAnchor link = null;
        List<HtmlAnchor> anchors = page.getAnchors();
        for (HtmlAnchor anchor : anchors) {
            String str = anchor.asText();

            if (anchor.asText().startsWith("LOG IN"))
               link = anchor;
        }


        HtmlPage newPage = link.click();
```

The problem that I am facing is that the "newPage" still remains on the old page whereas it should have taken me to another one.

My Webclient settings and options are :

```
    webClient.getOptions().setRedirectEnabled(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setUseInsecureSSL(true);
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(false);                                                         
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setCssEnabled(false);
    webClient.getOptions().setAppletEnabled(false);
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
    webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
```

Answer (score 0):

Resolved it , the below worked.

```
    webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true); 
    webClient.waitForBackgroundJavaScript(1000);
```